# Error with program.csh (bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory)

Tags: bash, command-line, scripts

I've installed a program from NASA, that use a `csh` command but I got the following error:

```
$ do_ledaps.csh L71124049_04920000912_MTL.txt
bash: /home/j/Documents/LEDAPStool/ledapsSrc/bin/do_ledaps.csh: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

The 4 submodules of the program work fine all of them, but this command to run all of them at once does not work.

I've also already set up the environment defining the export path in the `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/home/j/Documents/LEDAPStool/ledapsSrc/bin:$PATH
export ANC_PATH=/home/j/Documents/LEDAPStool/LedapsAnc
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C-Shell (csh) package is probably not installed.

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

Comment: @user53128: so you may consider to accept the answer clicking on the gray check under the number of votes.